# Repositioning Sender's details on Cover Letter

Tags: addresses

I'd like to reposition the sender's address details to the right side of the page, directly across from the receiver's information. This change will provide additional space for me to elaborate on the cover letter content. Currently, the sender's details are positioned below the receiver's details. Additionally, I'd like to move the date to the right side of the page. Can someone assist me with editing and organizing these modifications? Here is the current template, I am using for preparing my cover letter.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Plain Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (February 14, 2023)
%
% This template originates from:
% https://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Author:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[12pt]{letter} % Default font size of the document, can use values of 10pt, 11pt or 12pt, but you may need to adjust margins if reducing font size

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{fouriernc} % Use the URW Schoolbook L font, similar to New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{hyperref}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions and margins

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Paper size, change to letterpaper for US letter size
    top=2cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin
    left=3.25cm, % Left margin
    right=3.25cm, % Right margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\date{\raggedright\today} % Left-aligned date of the letter, use \today for the current date

\begin{letter}{
    % Name and address of the person to whom the letter is being sent
    To: 
    ABC \\
    Department LMN\\
    University of OPQ\\
    Country RST\\
    \bigskip
    
    From: XYZ \\
    Lecturer, Department UVW\\
    University of PQR\\
    Country RST
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME & ADDRESS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{center}
%   \large\bfseries % Font size and styling
%   Dr. John Dorian \\ % Your name
%   5384 N Broadway Ave \\ % Your address and phone number
%   Trotwood, Ohio 45426 \\
%   (937) 837-1234
%\end{center}

\vspace{1cm} % Vertical whitespace

\signature{Anwar Ahmad} % Your name for the signature at the bottom

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\opening{Dear Dr. ABC,}

PARAGRAPH ONE:

PARAGRAPH TWO: 

PARAGRAPH THREE: 
\bigskip

Yours Sincerely,

XYZ
%\ps{P.S. An additional note or description.} % A postscript line for additional information or descriptions
\bigskip
\bigskip
%\encl{Curriculum vitae, research activities summary, list of academic references} % List your enclosed documents here, comment this line for no enclosures

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```